# Generating JWT for java code where username is not unique

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I am working on java code for generating JWT but I am not able to generate JWT because in my database username is not unique we have multiple users with same username so it is getting confused which user to be selected.

My user in database gets unique when we take its username and id but so I tried to send username as issuer and id as subject to make it more secure but internally it is using its own method to validate user which is loadByUserName(String username) so I am not able to generate JWT when multiple users found in database with same username.

Comment: How are users logging in to your system if the username is not unique? What is passed as loginname is what needs to be in the JWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great if you will be able to share some code, but nevertheless, I can answer from conceptual point.

> so I tried to send username as issuer

Do not do that. `Issuer` as a claim is conceptually [meant to be a different thing](https://mojoauth.com/glossary/jwt-issuer/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20JSON%20Web%20Token,which%20the%20JWT%20was%20issued.). There are so many options to overcome your problem indeed.

Although the fact that you have non-unique username in the database is wired, but the id in the database for each user that you mentioned should be unique by itself, not just with combination with username. Therefore, you can:

1. Use id as `sub` claim in the token, so you can uniquely identity the user.
2. The JWT token may also have some custom claims, not defined in RFC, so you may have a claim named `qualifier` (just an example, choose name that does not clash with [standard claims](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1)) to represent the username and sub to represent the id or vice versa.
3. You can also construct the `subj` claim from username and id together like `username:id`, although the second options seems to be better.

> but internally it is using its own method to validate user which is
> `loadByUserName(String username)`

I guess you are talking about Spring Security `UserDetailsService` interface here. If so, then you can:

1. Provide your own implementation that is capable to load user by id if you have
2. Not use `BasicAuthenticationFilter` and `UserDetailsService` at all. In large projects you typically write your own filter in `FilterChain` since the auth mechanisms are quite complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it is helpful for me. Mikhalil2048 will you suggest any documentation name for JWT implementation on production level.

Comment: @Newbie I think that the best doc is the RFC doc here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519. This is the standard itself actually. BTW if this answer solves your problem please mark it as accepted :)